# How to put buttons like that?

Tags: android

[image]

Hello i want to put my number buttons(1 to 9) like that

but its now like that:

[image]

This is my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
        titleView.setText("Table Layout");
        titleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(titleView);




        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);



        Button btnConnect = new Button(this);
        btnConnect.setText("Connect");
        btnConnect.setLayoutParams(param2);
        layout2.addView(btnConnect);

        TextView titleViewSpace = new TextView(this);
        titleViewSpace.setLayoutParams(param2);
        layout2.addView(titleViewSpace);


        Button btnDisconnect = new Button(this);
        btnDisconnect.setText("Disconnect");
        btnDisconnect.setLayoutParams(param2);
        layout2.addView(btnDisconnect);

        layout.addView(layout2);

        TableLayout tblLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tblLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        TableRow tblrow = null;


        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 1) {
                tblrow = new TableRow(this);
                tblLayout.addView(tblrow);

            }
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("" + i);
            tblrow.addView(b);
        }




        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        Button btnZero = new Button(this);
        btnZero.setText("0");
        Button btnHash = new Button(this);
        btnHash.setText("#");
        Button btnStar = new Button(this);
        btnStar.setText("*");


        tr.addView(btnZero);
        tr.addView(btnHash);
        tr.addView(btnStar);


        tblLayout.addView(tr);
        layout.addView(tblLayout);


        setContentView(layout);
```

In order to have above view, i put buttons this layout

```
new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1)
```

However, when i put this layout to buttons(1 to 9), buttons in loop disappear. What might be the solution?

Comment: @real1 please do not post duplicate questions. it clutters the site. If you are still having trouble edit your previous question to include relevant new details. If the answer provided on your other question didn't work why did you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up weight sum and layout weight in google. These two properties will make the buttons take up the whole space of the screen.